# Login view controller best practice

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, segue, uistoryboardsegue

This isn't specifically a coding problem, I'm just looking for best practice as what I feel I'm doing at the moment seems like it could be optimised.

I am writing an iOS app that requires users to login.

I have written a user authentication PHP web service that returns JSON based on the email and password parameters of a HTTP POST request. I have methods that handle success and failure on the client side.

At the moment, when the app is launched, the user is presented with a login view controller. On successful login, a basic push segue is performed to the 'home' view controller which says something like 'hey welcome xxx' at the moment.

If the user has already authenticated once on the device I want to persist their details and just automatically load the 'home' view controller at launch.

Do you think I should present the login view controller as a modal on top? or is my current setup ok? or is there a much better way of doing this? Big gaps in my knowledge here.

Also, how do I load a different root view controller on launch rather than what is set in the storyboard?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would present a modal view controller from the app delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

something like

[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:signInViewController animated:NO];
do this after

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
then when you are finished with the sign-in view controller you can dismiss it the same as you would any modal view controller

Answer (score 0):

> Also, how do I load a different root view controller on launch rather than what is set in the storyboard?

Well, if you choose to display a modal login view controller on top of your segue, this is no issue at all; possibly you should try this, since it is a pretty standard way of dealing with login views and it is extremely easy.

Otherwise, if you want to go with your current design, I would first check that the stored credentials are still ok, then (if ok) I would simply do a push segue to the home controller from the login view controller...